# Change pinned row color while selecting ag-grid row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am currently working on Ag Grid.initial load i have changed the pinned row color with the help of below code.

```
<ag-grid-angular[getRowStyle]="getRowStyle">
 </ag-grid-angular>

 getRowStyle(params: any): any {
    if (params.node.rowPinned === 'top') {
      return {'font-weight': '400',
              'background-color': 'blue' };
    }
  }
```

Do we have any other way to change the background color of pinned row on **selectionChanged** event.

expecting a better suggestion

Thanks in advance.